What type of infinitival clause is “... to turn back” in "It was impossible to turn back"?
The sentence is:

It was impossible to turn back.

What type of infinitival clause is this? What is its syntactic function and what are its other grammatical attributes?
Is it the complement of the adjective impossible?

to turn back = subject w/infinitive ; was impossible = predicate

I’m temporarily this question so I can reöpen it to clear the spurious close votes.

This is an exact duplicate of Which sentence element is the to-infinitive after an empty subject 'it'? (answered by BillJ in a comment). It is essentially two questions: the use of to-infinitives as subjects (covered at What is the difference between using gerunds vs {to-}infinitives as the subject of a sentence?), and extraposition ...

(covered in the above-mentioned question). ELU only allows one [potential] duplicate to be cited in the set closure reason. I chose the one I thought might be harder to find.



It was impossible to turn back.


This infinitive is what we call the extraposed subject of the verb BE. The sentence means:


To turn back was impossible.


Sentence (2)  is a bit clunky in English. English speakers don't like to use clauses (whether finite or infinitival) as Subjects. To rectify this, we insert the meaningless dummy pronoun it as the subject and shunt the infinitive down to the end of the larger
clause.
Note that because this infinitival clause functions as extraposed subject, the subject of the infinitival clause itself is not grammatically determined. We cannot say for sure, without the further information provided by the context, who the notional subject of the predicate to turn back is.
